# Google script for sending email if cell value is below certain value issue

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

Very new to javascript. Probably very obvious/easy solution to this for someone that knows.

Trying to write a script that sends an email if a cell value drops below 100 and changes the cell colour  to blue:

I have tried to write it by calling a function:

```
function sendemails() {
  var emailAddress = "email@address.com"; 
  var message = "test body";
  var subject = "test subject";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}

function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getValue() < 100) {
  range.setBackgroundColor('blue');
 }

  if(range.getValue() < 100) {
  sendemails()

  }
}
```

I have also just tried sending the mail directly:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getValue() < 100) {
  range.setBackgroundColor('blue');
 }

  if(range.getValue() < 100) {
  var emailAddress = "email@address.com"; 
  var message = "test body";
  var subject = "test subject";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

  }
}
```

I cant get either to work, probably as I haven't called the function correctly or have missed something obvious. The cell changes to blue, and if I run the sendemails function by itself, not as a result of onedit it sends an email. Im just struggling to call it.

Any help or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The MailApp part seems correct. Can you please post the code with where the onEdit method are called / referenced?

Comment: This is the only code I have saved in the script. onedit is a function within google scripts I believe? (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit)

Comment: Sorry, my bad there.

Comment: No worries, any thoughts on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is quite simple, and Google has stated it in the developer guide:

> Because simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user
>   for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions:
>
> - They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

Please see the section "Restrictions" [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/index?hl=en-en).

To work around this issue, you can create a normal function `sendEmail()`. This function can be added as a installable trigger, and will then be allowed to call services that require authorization. You can read more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en#google_apps_triggers).

The code for sending mails would then look like this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if (range.getValue() < 100){
     var emailAddress = "email@example.com";
     var message = "test body";
     var subject = "test subject";
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah found that shortly after posting this, cheets though heskja!

Comment: Hi Heskja, any chance you can help with this issue at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551543/pull-csv-to-google-sheets-with-basic-authentication

Comment: Hi Heskja, any chance you can help with this issue at all, im very stuck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273210/use-headers-with-import-json