# Pull csv to Google Sheets with basic authentication

Tags: javascript, csv, google-docs, basic-authentication

I need to pull a csv from a URL that requires basic auth.

I have found this code that works, apart from parsing the csv, clearing and setting the cells. I think there is a few bugs as it is old code, such as `clear.contents()` should be `clear.content()`.

And even with hard coding the data in where sheets is, im still struggling to get it to work, has anyone else found a solution?:

```
// this function assumes the CSV has no fields with commas,
// and strips out all the double quotes
function parseCsvResponse(csvString) {
    var retArray = [];

    var strLines = csvString.split(/\n/g);
    var strLineLen = strLines.length;
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; strLineLen; i++) {
        var line = strLines[i];
        if (line != '') {
            retArray.push(line.replace(/"/g, "").split(/,/));
        }
    }

    return retArray;
}

function populateSheetWithCSV(sheet, csvUrl, user, pw) {

    // request the CSV!
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl, {
        headers: {
            // use basic auth
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)
        }
    });

    // parse the response as a CSV
    var csvContent = parseCsvResponse(resp.getContentText());

    // clear everything in the sheet
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();

    // set the values in the sheet (as efficiently as we know how)
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvContent.length /* rows */, csvContent[0].length /* columns */).setValues(csvContent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I haven't seen your CSV file, it's not that easy to predict where things goes wrong. However, I found that changing the regular expression in the `parseCsvResponse` method to include `\r` fixed the problem for me. Thus, the line reads

> var strLines = csvString.split(/\n|\r/g);

Secondly, I can't see where you get the `sheet`-variable from. I used the following line of code:

> var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

Lastly, I noticed that the script requested authorization when I tried to run it. I assume you have granted the permissions required?